# Copy new directory from one TFS branch to another

Tags: tfs

Another developer has some test files in a new directory in their branch. They're useful to me as well but I'm working in a totally independent, newer branch and he's not likely to merge his branch anytime soon.

I am able to branch his "test-data" directory into my branch but I really want to break the branch association so they're treated as new files in my branch, i.e. so TFS thinks our branches independently added the same new files and we resolve conflicts later since our test data is likely to diverge.

Is there a way to "orphan" the branched files somehow?

Comment: Why not just get the files from him, and add them to your branch by hand?

Comment: Because you can't just "get files" in TFS, you have to mess about mapping directories. And I don't want to have to wait for him to be able to email them across or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* just get files in TFS using the web access component. Just browse to the folder through the code portion of web access and `right click > get as zip.`

You can do it from the command line as well but I am not familiar with that. SO has a lot of resources on how to do that from what I have seen.

It is possible to break the branching relationship in TFS and there are many questions on SO on how to do that. But your branch wouldn't initially treat them as 'added' and the history will be in TFS. I would recommend branching just the folder his useful code into your branch and leaving that relationship for posterities sake.

That being said, depending on your situation it may not make sense. If you want to remove the branching relationship immediately, then I don't think you need to use TFS.

Comment: I don't know we have a web-client set up, although it's interesting you can do things that way which aren't apparently possible in the desktop client proper!

Comment: Do you have the **Web Access** node under the *Home* view of Team Explorer?

Comment: You can also map an individual file / folder  and view individual files from the server without mapping in Visual Studio.

Comment: It's called "Web Portal" but apparently we do - useful!